# How to add random position of image in css by the x

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make a random position of image ".block" and make the auto reset of function when it flies down. Big thanks to everybody who will help. :)

```js
var player = document.getElementById("player");
var block = document.getElementById("block");

function goleft(argument) {
  player.classList.add("animatel");

  setTimeout(function() {
    player.classList.remove("animatel");
  }, 1);

  console.log("left");
}

function goright(argument) {
  player.classList.add("animater");

  console.log("right");
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.player {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 450px;
}

.block {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
  animation: block 1s infinite linear;
}

#game {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

@keyframes block {
  0% {
    top: -50;
  }
  100% {
    top: 420;
  }
}

@keyframes gor {
  0% {
    left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 450px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0px;
  }
}

@keyframes gol {
  0% {
    right: 450px;
  }
  50% {
    right: 0px;
  }
  100% {
    right: 450px;
  }
}

.animater {
  animation: gor 1s;
  position: relative;
}

.animatel {
  animation: gol 1s;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="game">

    <div id="player"><img class="player" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="player box"></div>
    <div id="block"><img class="block" src="https://via.placeholder.com/80" alt="bogdan"></div>
    <button onclick="goleft()">left</button>
    <button onclick="goright()">right</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to explain better what you're trying to do and what's going wrong.

Comment: Try using Math.random() and setting the images values based on the with and height of the game box https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random